# Exit flowchart blocks only if specific condition is true in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am currently using `queue`- and `delay`-blocks and I want the agents inside of them only to exit if certain conditions are true.
I have used certain `if-else` blocks which did not work. I am using ANyLogic as stated in the question so it is basically Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this outside of flow blocks, for example with a cyclic event:

Put your if-else check in there. If the condition is met, call `myQueueBlock.remove(theAgentToRemove)` or `myDelayBlock.remove(theAgentToRemove)`

NOTE that it is your responsibility to decide which agent to remove (hence the `theAgentToRemove`). If you want to remove the `i`th agent, you could use `myQueueBlock.remove(myQueueBlock.get(i))`. But you must manage this

NOTE also that your agents will be outside of any flow chart block after calling these commands. If you need them to join another block somewhere, you need to use an "Enter" block and call `myEnterBlock.take(theAgentToRemove)` from within the Event